# How to make Infopath form responsive?

Tags: infopath

I would like to know in detail how can we make the form responsive.
Which can be seen easily in any device.

Comment: Please add more details to your question. Describe the form you are creating. Which version of SharePoint are you using? What have you tried already?

Comment: Do you have to use Infopath ? Maybe a simple form with a few javascript and CSS dedicated for the responsiveness would be enough.
I don't know your case, but that's how I would do it.

Answer (score 3):

Using Infopath form it's not possible to make it 100% responsive. All I was able to find was [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Design-a-form-template-for-use-on-a-mobile-device-c8afdd6d-280f-40b6-9348-28077d8d34d6?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#BM4_7_) 2007 article.

Also [Microsoft](http://blogs.office.com/2014/01/31/update-on-infopath-and-sharepoint-forms/) is [retiring](http://sp2013.blogspot.com/2014/03/infopath-is-dead-long-live-excel-survey.html) InfoPath and 2013 is the last version of its kind.

You should change your approach from InfoPath to a ListForm, and use that along with JSLinks etc. to make it fully responsive.

Comment: Adding to Amal's answer, InfoPath manages its own rendering on the browser output (the HTML generated).  There really isn't anyway to customize this or improve upon it.  Your best option for a responsive form is custom application pages or web parts rather than InfoPath.